# How to use datatime conditions in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010

How to use below condition in crystal Report 2018

```
if {@IntParIssDate}>='03/25/2018' then
IntPartTax = ({@totintpartcost} * 5 /100 )
```

If IntParIssDate >= '03/25/2018' then IntPartTax will be 5 % of totintpartcost

How to calculate this.

Thaks

Comment: What is `IntPartTax`, a variable?

Comment: @MatSnow yes  , it is variable

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
NumberVar IntPartTax;

if {@IntParIssDate}>=date(2018,3,25) then
   IntPartTax := ({@totintpartcost} * 5/100)
```